# Shuffling parameters of a pretrained model in pytroch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I imported a pretrained resnet50 in Pytorch and I want to shuffle the weights, how can it be done?
I have done this-

```
    model_conv = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
                                                                                                    
    for param in model_conv.parameters():
       torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=param, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have downloaded a pretrained resnet50, I want to shuffle the weights of each layer. I just want to access the weights and shuffle them.